# Will this site be participating in Winter Bash 2014?

Tags: support, winter-bash

Winter Bash 2014 will be starting soon, and if [this meta Math post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17368/would-you-like-some-hats-yes-please) is to be believed, it is now opt-out rather than opt-in. That means that unless the moderators of a given site inform Stack Exchange that they don't want to participate by December 1st, that site will be included.

However, that raises some question as to what the status of this site will be. We don't yet have pro tempore moderators appointed. They may or may not be appointed by December 1st. A strict reading of the policies leads me to believe that we would be included automatically, but it could just as easily go the other way.

**What are the plans for Winter Bash on this site?** If there is no definite plan and we want to judge the community's opinions, I can modify this into a [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) question to do the necessary polling, but I figure it's better to check whether there's a clear plan either way first before making such a post myself.

<sup>For what it's worth, I'm in favor of us participating, but I'm [more than a little bit biased](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/01/winter-bash-2013-wrap-up/) in saying that.</sup>

Comment: I hope so, that was some of good harmless winter cheer in some of the other sites. Humbugs be blasted! :)))

Comment: The meta post you link to is in-line with information I received from SE as a moderator on MESE.

Comment: Does anyone want to post a 'We shouldn't participate!' answer? Just to be interesting? I know that's not the focus of the question, but still. . .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't seen any strong anti-headgear campaigning 'round these parts, so this site will have hats in Winter Bash 2014! For any of you who wish to continue using the site in "unadorned mode," there will be an "I hate hats" option you can enable once the festivities start.

I was hoping to have pro-tem mods sorted for you by now, who could help coordinate this decision, but it's been kind of crazy and I just haven't been able to. I'm working on it right now. I apologize for the delay (on multiple levels).

Answer (score 1):

First off - I'm glad that somebody brought this up, instead of hoping that pro-tem mods will be named by December 1 and one of *them* will bring it up.

Second - I say we go for it!

[image]

(from [here](http://www.nerdytshirt.com/images/hat-images/push-limits/push-limits-math-hat-front3.jpg))

---

As for a clear plan. . . Well, I don't know that there is one, if we want to participate. We'll get hats by default, like you said.