# Do we want hats?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, winter-bash

It's December, and once again, Winter Bash is almost upon us.

For anyone not familiar with it, [Winter Bash](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/winterbash/info) is an end-of-the-year celebration on Stack Exchange, where users can earn "hats" to wear on their profile pictures by doing certain things.

Each site can choose whether or not to participate. However, unless there is a large consensus against participating, the site will automatically participate. Those who don't want to go along can click the "I hate hats" button in the footer.

So what does everyone say? Do we want hats this year?

For information from last year, see [Will this site be participating in Winter Bash 2014?](https://hsm.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168/will-this-site-be-participating-in-winter-bash-2014).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Give an *upvote* to this answer if you **do** want hats, and *downvote* if you **do not** want hats during this Winter Bash.

**EDIT: We have hats!** Answer score was 7/0 (up/downvotes).