# Do we want hats (2016 edition)?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash

The end of the year is rapidly approaching and, as last year, and the year before that, and all the years before that since before the beginning of time... The Winter Bash event is coming up! If you don't know what that means, please have a look [at last year's post](https://hsm.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/249/do-we-want-hats), which has some more information.

The main point of the Winter Bash event is that, for a short period of time, users can earn "hats" which they may use to decorate their profile pictures. We participated during last two events, but as every year it's probably best to give you guys, the community, a chance to let us know whether you'd like to do so again, or would rather like to opt *out* of the event this time around. What do you guys think?

Answer (score 7):

Please **upvote this answer if you would like for this site to participate in the Winter Bash 2016**, or **downvote this answer if you would like for this site not to participate**.